# getEllipsisCount return 0 in kotlin textview to know it's ellipsizing

Tags: android, kotlin

I have to know when text is cross the limit of textview depend on it's hight, not maxline. I have to load some long text in multiple textview. like book pages in book reader.

```
lLayout.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            // your code here. `this` should work
            val l = tvHtml.getLayout();
            if (l != null) {
                var lines = l.getLineCount()
                if (lines > 0) {
                    if (l.getEllipsisCount(lines - 1) > 0) {//2147483647
                        Log.d("log ---------", "Text is ellipsized")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

I have written this code to know ellipsizing but, it returns 0 in `l.getEllipsisCount(lines - 1)`

Answer (score 0):

ViewTreeObserver doesn't work well in my case so this is what i used :

```
  yourTxtView.post {
            if (yourTxtView.lineCount > 0) {
                // do your stuff
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have to know text cross the limit of textview depend on it's hight. If it crosses then remaining text load in the next textview like book pages.

Comment: @NIKUNJGADHIYA what would be the limit of textview suppose your text view height is 100 so is it crossing the limit or not?

Comment: Thanks for your support. I try to build an app like amazon kindle, with free text formate without any formate like pdf and all.